# Spark Dataframe count doesn't return the same results when run twice

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, apache-spark-sql

Using Spark 1.5.1, Hive 1.2.1

When I run this snippet under `spark-shell --master yarn --deploy-mode client`:

```
val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)

var queryLeft = "SELECT t1.* FROM (SELECT t2.*, row_number() over (PARTITION BY CAST(TRIM(t2.pk) as DECIMAL(31,8)) ORDER BY t2.create_dt DESC) AS R FROM myschema.mytable t2 WHERE t2.part_dt='mydate' AND t2.part_seq='myseq') t1 WHERE t1.R = 1"

val dfLeft = hiveContext.sql(queryLeft)
val firstCount = dfLeft.count
val secondCount = dfLeft.count
```

I get this result, which are both wrong (and unequal!!)

```
scala> print (firstCount, secondCount)
(1865,2373)
```

When I run the same snippet under `spark-shell`, I get the right results

```
scala> print (firstCount, secondCount)
(2395,2395)
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrongly?

Comment: Are you sure it's reading from the same place ?

Comment: @eliasah my code is exactly as written above. No changes are done to hive or hdfs whatsoever in the 5 seconds it takes to run the code. So yes, I would assume it's reading from the same place.

Comment: could u figure it out what was the cause of it. I also get different records in my dataframe when I use a join!